# wordpress pagination issue with wp-pagenavi

Tags: pagination, wordpress

Trying to add pagination to my wordpress theme using WP-PageNavi.
In my localhost, it works just fine...
however, online it fails to show the Prev Next buttons...
my loop is:

```
 <?php query_posts( array( 'cat' => 19, 'showposts' => 6, 'paged' => get_query_var('paged') ) ); ?>
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

   <div class="xxxx">
   <h4> <?php the_date('l, j \d\e F, Y');?> </h4>
   <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1></a>

   <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
   </div>
   <?php endwhile?>                
   <?php else: ?>               
   <?php endif; ?>

   <div class="yyyyyy"> 
   <?php wp_pagenavi( ); ?>
    </div>
```

Any idea of how to fix this?
spent all day trying to make it work... :-(

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of what this looks like?

Comment: Thanks for you comment!
actually, nothing happens... in my local version it works...
but online, prev and next links just don't appear!
tried to uninstall plugins... deleted... but still the same...

Comment: Can you show what it looks like in local version?

Comment: Are you sure you have enough posts on your online version for it to work? They only show up if there's more than the posts_per_page.

Comment: Duhhh!!!Good tip! @StevenJones!
however... as I've cnahged the permanent link structure to '/%postname%/'
when I press next, it shows the same page.....
do you have any idea of how to fix that?